# What does 迫不及待 开始倒计 mean?

Tags: translation, characters, simplified-characters

This line came from 深呼吸 by Yu Quan 羽泉。
迫不及待 - anxious to wait
开始倒计 - begin counting down

Would it just be translate as 'anxious to wait, I begin to count down'?

Answer (score 2):

迫不及待 - cannot wait anymore

开始倒计 - begin counting down (which means the thing you are waiting for will start soon)

Answer (score 0):

I believe 开始倒计 is just an unusual weird abbreviation for Chinese rhythm. People normally say 开始倒计时 to mean "start the countdown".

> 开始 start, begin
>
> 倒计时 (verb) count down, (noun) countdown

Chinese rhythm requires four characters per pause, therefore it is unusually abbreviated to 开始倒计.

---

迫不及待 is an ancient Chinese idiom for "can't wait anymore".